# Apply Follow path on top of a animation

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path

I made an animation with a rig, and now I want to apply a follow path to a curve, so the mesh is doing an animation in a loop and following that curve. The problem is that to make "follow path" work I have to apply the animation, and that overwrites my rig animation.

[image]

The animation is in the rig, so I also tried to apply the follow path to the mesh instead but the mesh moves independently of the rig and it just moves away and deforms itself. There is any way to link the mesh to the bones so it moves at the same time, or any other solution to make it work?

Comment: it depends how your animation looks like and on what bones the animations are. "normally" you would do the follow path bone constraint on the root bone (which you hopefully didn't animate) and then it should work

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to apply the animation"? You can add a follow curve constraint to an armature even it has an action.